# How to merge sql query with union into one query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like to get the results of the below query with just one query not by using union. 
My query is as below

I am generating a SSRS chart this query, so need to merge the query into one and get a proper result as shown in table 2

```
select 
    res.Count, res.Month, res.status, res.SortOrder 
from 
    (SELECT 
        count(analysis_complete_date) as Count,
        DATENAME(month, analysis_complete_date) AS Month, 
        DATEPART(month, analysis_complete_date) AS SortOrder,
        'Analysis' as status
     FROM  
        SCN_Part_Details AS parts
     WHERE  
        analysis_complete_date BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-11'
     GROUP BY 
        DATENAME(month, analysis_complete_date), 
        DATEPART(month, analysis_complete_date)

     union

     SELECT 
        count(Act_Supp_Negotiation_Date) as Count,
        DATENAME(month, Act_Supp_Negotiation_Date) AS Month, 
        DATEPART(month, Act_Supp_Negotiation_Date) AS SortOrder,
        'Negotiated' as status
     FROM  
        SCN_Part_Details AS parts
     WHERE  
        Act_Supp_Negotiation_Date BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-11'
     GROUP BY 
        DATENAME(month, Act_Supp_Negotiation_Date), 
        DATEPART(month, Act_Supp_Negotiation_Date) ) as res
order by 
    res.SortOrder
```

This will give a result like:

Table 1

```
Count          Month          Status     SortOrder
--------------------------------------------------
167            January       Analysis     1
631            January       Negotiated   1
70             February      Analysis     2
237            February      Negotiated   2
```

and so on..

I want a result like this:

Table 2

```
AnalysisCount    NegotiatedCount    Month       SortOrder
---------------------------------------------------------
167                 631             January      1
70                  237             February     2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give it a try:

```
 ;WITH CTEResult AS 
(
    select 
        res.Count, res.Month, res.status, res.SortOrder 
    from 
        (SELECT 
            count(analysis_complete_date) as Count,
            DATENAME(month, analysis_complete_date) AS Month, 
            DATEPART(month, analysis_complete_date) AS SortOrder,
            'Analysis' as status
         FROM  
            SCN_Part_Details AS parts
         WHERE  
            analysis_complete_date BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-11'
         GROUP BY 
            DATENAME(month, analysis_complete_date), 
            DATEPART(month, analysis_complete_date)

         union

         SELECT 
            count(Act_Supp_Negotiation_Date) as Count,
            DATENAME(month, Act_Supp_Negotiation_Date) AS Month, 
            DATEPART(month, Act_Supp_Negotiation_Date) AS SortOrder,
            'Negotiated' as status
         FROM  
            SCN_Part_Details AS parts
         WHERE  
            Act_Supp_Negotiation_Date BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-11'
         GROUP BY 
            DATENAME(month, Act_Supp_Negotiation_Date), 
            DATEPART(month, Act_Supp_Negotiation_Date) ) as res
)

SELECT DISTINCT
  (SELECT TOP 1 Count FROM CTEResult A WHERE A.Month = C.Month AND A.STATUS =  'Analysis' AND A.SortOrder = C.SortOrder) AS  AnalysisCount,
  (SELECT TOP 1 Count FROM CTEResult B WHERE B.Month = C.Month AND B.STATUS =  'Negotiated' AND B.SortOrder = C.SortOrder) AS  
    NegotiatedCount, C.Month, C.SortOrder 
FROM CTEResult C
```

Comment: Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 72
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 76
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 78
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Comment: I was unable to test. Because of no data. Changed the query, retest it. Try adding data to sqlfiddle.

Comment: This gives me the desired result but with one simple correction, It gives 2 same results. Like 631 167 January 1 and same row duplicates once more.

Comment: Yes, it will come we need to use group by or Distinct. I updated with distinct. Is, it helped you?

Answer (score 0):

Once you got your result, you can pivot the table to get the desired result.

```
create table #temp
(
    quantity int,
    month varchar(20),
    status varchar(20),
    sortorder int
)

insert into #temp values                                
(167,'January' ,'Analysis', 1    ),
(631,'January' ,'Negotiated',1   ),
(70 ,'February','Analysis', 2    ),
(237,'February','Negotiated', 2  )


select max(analysis) as analysiscount    
      ,max(negotiated) as negotiatedcount    
      ,month
      ,max(sortorder) as sortorder    
from 
    (
        select * 
        from #temp
        pivot
            (max(quantity) for status in ([analysis],[negotiated])) as pi
    ) t
group by month
order by sortorder;
```

Comment: I would like to the change the query. As I am going to use the query result for SSRS charts.

Comment: I mean to say that I do not want to pivot and get the result. Instead I would like to change the query itself and get the result.

Comment: That is my requirement, I want query without union. And get the result like in Table 2

Comment: There are some ways to do that, but without the table structure its kinda hard...